# OpenEdge ABL UI Freeze window until Popup closes

Tags: window, openedge

I'm using OpenEdge ABL to create a window that will run a secondary window on the touch of a button. However I am trying to get the first/parent window to freeze while the child window is running and resume when the child window closes.

I attempted to use WAIT-FOR WINDOW-CLOSE OF CURRENT-WINDOW on the parent window however this returned the error: Invalid widget handle used in WAIT-FOR statement. WAIT-FOR terminated (4122).

To run the child window I use:

```
RUN D:\adherenceEdit_12875-Win.w(cUserId,cShiftCode,dtDate).
```

Comment: You need to show all of the code for both windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this was by adding:

```
 DO WITH FRAME {&FRAME-NAME}:
```

Making the sensitivity of the buttons false meant that they would not be pressed while the child window was running.

```
  ASSIGN CURRENT-WINDOW:SENSITIVE = FALSE.


  RUN D:\adherenceEdit_12875-Win.w(INPUT cUserId,
                                   INPUT cShiftCode,
                                   INPUT dtDate).
```

After the child was closed the parent window continues running and resets the buttons sensitivity allowing them to be pressed

```
  ASSIGN CURRENT-WINDOW:SENSITIVE = TRUE.

 END.
```

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to do this and @nwahmaet's answer may have provided a more efficient method.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to make the child window modal?

I think you can look into using the [`TOP-ONLY`](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/abl-reference/page/TOP-ONLY-attribute.html#TOP-ONLY-attribute) or [`ALWAYS-ON-TOP`](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/abl-reference/page/ALWAYS-ON-TOP-attribute.html) attributes on the window, or make the child a [dialog box](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/abl-reference/page/DIALOG-BOX-widget.html).

Comment: Yes, the simplest solution would be to make the child a dialog box. This is modal by default.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do this by hiding the Main Window while the Popup is opened...

```
    // Replace the C-Win to window's name - Not required to specify the frame
    C-Win:VISIBLE = FALSE.
    RUN My_Program.w.
    C-Win:VISIBLE = TRUE.
```